# How to execute an eclipse app in console mode

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, tycho

I've developed an eclipse RCP application. My UI is a plugin executed within the  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application Application.

I have it building and running perfectly thanks to Tycho.

Now I want to get rid of this UI plugin, which went obsolete as I'm using a servlet to interact with the application.
My goal is to have it started from a bash command line.

What should I change in my product configuration to have the eclipse application executed from the command line, with the minimum set of change?

I thought I could simply set it up in my Product Definition. (I suppose I was wrong).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are still searching, the answer is indeed in the Producct definition, in the VM arguments:

```
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.console=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true
```